# Parsing text file in python using pyparsing

Tags: python, pyparsing

I am trying to parse the following text using pyparsing.

```
acp (SOLO1,
     "solo-100",
     "hi here is the gift"
     "Maximum amount of money, goes",
     430, 90)

jhk (SOLO2,
     "solo-101",
     "hi here goes the wind."
     "and, they go beyond",
     1000, 320)
```

I have tried the following code but it doesn't work.

```
flag = Word(alphas+nums+'_'+'-')
enclosed = Forward()
nestedBrackets = nestedExpr('(', ')', content=enclosed)
enclosed << (flag | nestedBrackets)

print list(enclosed.searchString (str1))
```

The comma(,) within the quotation is producing undesired results.

Comment: There is no need to define nestedExpr with a Forward - nestedExpr will take care of all of the parenthetical nesting. For this, you just need `section = flag + nestedExpr(content=Word(nums) | flag | quotedString)` and then parse for `OneOrMore(section)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I might have oversimplified slightly in my comments - here is a more complete
answer.

If you don't really have to deal with nested data items, then a single-level parenthesized
data group in each section will look like this:

```
LPAR,RPAR = map(Suppress, "()")
ident = Word(alphas, alphanums + "-_")
integer = Word(nums)

# treat consecutive quoted strings as one combined string
quoted_string = OneOrMore(quotedString)
# add parse action to concatenate multiple adjacent quoted strings
quoted_string.setParseAction(lambda t: '"' + 
                            ''.join(map(lambda s:s.strip('"\''),t)) + 
                            '"' if len(t)>1 else t[0])
data_item = ident | integer | quoted_string

# section defined with no nesting
section = ident + Group(LPAR + delimitedList(data_item) + RPAR)
```

I wasn't sure if it was intentional or not when you omitted the comma between
two consecutive quoted strings, so I chose to implement logic like Python's compiler,
in which two quoted strings are treated as just one longer string, that is `"AB CD " "EF"` is 
the same as `"AB CD EF"`.  This was done with the definition of quoted_string, and adding
the parse action to quoted_string to concatenate the contents of the 2 or more component 
quoted strings.

Finally, we create a parser for the overall group

```
results = OneOrMore(Group(section)).parseString(source)
results.pprint()
```

and get from your posted input sample:

```
[['acp',
  ['SOLO1',
   '"solo-100"',
   '"hi here is the giftMaximum amount of money, goes"',
   '430',
   '90']],
 ['jhk',
  ['SOLO2',
   '"solo-101"',
   '"hi here goes the wind.and, they go beyond"',
   '1000',
   '320']]]
```

If you *do* have nested parenthetical groups, then your section definition can be
as simple as this:

```
# section defined with nesting
section = ident + nestedExpr()
```

Although as you have already found, this will retain the separate commas as if they
were significant tokens instead of just data separators.